# entity framework : migration deleted but still deployed

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am working on a project which uses entity framework. There is a migration where a table is readded although the same table is added in a previous migration. I ran the migration and updated database locally (the table was missing from my local environment). Now when I deploy the application to the QA environment using teamcity, I get error that the table already exist which is correct as on the QA environment the table is already present. I have deleted the migration and redeployed it on QA but the migration is still being run. I am fairly new to EF and am unable to figure out how the deleted migration is still a part of deployment and how can I fix this so that the migration to add the existing table is not run. Any help is appreciable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Target the database to a previous migration that the table exists:

```
Update-Database -TargetMigration <string>
```

Delete the migations that u have created after your target migration.

Then check if the table model does not exist and add new migration and update it.